# Meaning of a group on a vector space?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have just started reading 'Representation Theory' by Fulton and Harris and I am confused about the meaning of on of their first lines:

> A *representation* of a finite group G on a finite-dimensional complex vector space V...

I am slightly confused about how we can have a group on a vector space. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: There isn't a "group $G$ on a finite-dimensional complex vector space", but there is "a representation of a group $G$ on a finite-dimensional vector space".

Comment: @Quantum You've parsed the phrase as "a representation of a [group on a vector space]", but the correct reading is "[a representation of a group] on a vector space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original formulation of representation theory was to take an abstract group and "represent" it as a subgroup matrices. That is, you want to view a group as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf{C})$ of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with complex entries.

Since the group $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf{C})$ acts on the vector space $\mathbf{C}^n$, if you view a group $G$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf{C})$ then $G$ acts on $\mathbf{C}^n$ and we call this a representation of $G$ on $\mathbf{C}^n$.

Thus, as Omnomnomnom pointed out, you don't have a "group on a vector space" you have a "group (that acts) on a vector space".

As an example, the group $(\mathbf{Z}, +)$ is isomorphic to the matrix group
$$ \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : n \in \mathbf{Z} \right\} $$
so you have a map $\mathbf{Z} \to \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbf{C})$ and this map is called a representation of $\mathbf{Z}$ on $\mathbf{C}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "a group on a vector space".  What is being defined here is the entire phrase "a representation of a group on a vector space".  All that is being assumed about $G$ and $V$ is that $G$ is a (finite) group and $V$ is a (finite-dimensional complex) vector space.

Note also that this phrase should be parsed as "(a representation of a group) on a vector space".  In general, a "representation" of a group $G$ is just a homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group of some object (so you "represent" elements of $G$ as automorphisms of the object); in this case the object is a vector space.